# Generate URL with Variable

Tags: php, curl

Hopefully, someone can spot the error, what I need to do is to first fetch the webpage for a token, then curl the new url with the token attached;

here is my code

```
$text = $siteName;

  if (preg_match('/;t=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{43})%3D/',$text,$matches)) {
// Match... vjVQa1PpcFMYuRsz10_H-1z41mWWe8d6ENEnBLE7gug
  echo 'TOKEN: '.$matches[1];

$curltube = curl_init ();
curl_setopt ($curltube, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.veoh.com/watch?v=opQ9GzRe5qs".$matches[1]);
curl_setopt ($curltube, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0 );
curl_setopt ($curltube, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie8.txt"); 
$curltubeplay = curl_exec ($curltube);
curl_close ($curltube);

echo $curltubeplay;
} else {
// No match
}
```

and the previous code before that fetches the web-page

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.veoh.com/watch?v=opQ9GzRe5qs");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0 );
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie8.txt");
```

so hopefully, someone can shed some light

Comment: When you say spot the error, it'd be helpful if you told is what was going wrong...

Comment: is your code finding the token? what is the token? what are you expecting the URL to be after you append the token? what is the URL you end up with?

Comment: oh sorry, I mean what I want to do is have this url http://www.veoh.com/watch?v=opQ9GzRe5qs&t= "$matches", so basically extract &t= and insert it into the new url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My *guess* (please expand the question to be clear) is that you expect to build a URL like this:

```
http://www.veoh.com/watch?v=opQ9GzRe5qs;t=abc
```

But you are building one like this:

```
http://www.veoh.com/watch?v=opQ9GzRe5qsabc
```

There are two simple fixes. This one takes the whole matched string, not just the token:

```
curl_setopt ($curltube, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.veoh.com/watch?v=opQ9GzRe5qs".$matches[0])
```

And this one adds back in the missing parts to the URL:

```
curl_setopt ($curltube, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.veoh.com/watch?v=opQ9GzRe5qs;t=".$matches[1])
```

Comment: got it, i had to add another . after the $ so it looks like this  "http://www.veoh.com/watch?v=opQ9GzRe5qs;t=".$matches[1].)